# Need help catching GwtQuery Datepicker select event

Tags: gwtquery

I want to execute some code when a date is selected using the Datepicker widget that is packaged with the [GWT Query UI](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-ui/) plug-in.

My attempt is below. The widget appears on the screen, and is apparently operational; but the callback function does not fire. Can you see where I have gone wrong?

```
$("#pick").as(Ui).datepicker().bind(Datepicker.Event.onSelect, new Function() {
  public boolean f(Event e, Object data) {
    Window.alert("Date selected");
    return true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with the GwtQuery developer by email, I arrived at a [work-around](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-ui/issues/detail?id=7) for what appears to be a bug.